# How to manually populate Many-To-Many fields through JSON fixture in Django

Tags: python, json, django, many-to-many, django-fixtures

I have a JSON fixture and I want to populate a many-to-many field from my JSON fixture but it seems Django only wants just one pk but I need to pass in a lot of integers representing pks for the other related fields.

IS there anyway to go about this.

I have used a `raw_id = ['reference(my table name)']` in the `ModelAdmin` so that pks  can be used to reference the related fields.

The error message is

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 142, in Deserializer
>       raise base.DeserializationError.WithData(e, d['model'], d.get('pk'), pk)
>   django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/user/Desktop/File/data/file.json':
>
> `[u"',' value must be an integer."]: (kjv.verse:pk=1) field_value was ','`

Comment: I figured out how to do it thanks. I had to enclose the pk's in a list. like `[1,2,3]`@Anoop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONField()` for django model

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
raw_id=JSONField(primary_key=True,db_index=True,null=True)
```

S0 your database will be like `{raw_id:[1,2,3,4]}`